# Android Default Screen when clicking Home Button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-activity

I implemented a Splash Screen of my Android App....and I have a custom home button in my action bar that when click, it will be redirected to my dashboard Activity and not to my splash screen..Do you have any idea how to implement it?? I am newbie regarding android Application...

Please show me how to do it..I can't get any idea how to code it...

Any Responses are highly appreciated..Thanks

My menu item code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuitem1:
            //code to be inserted here but I dont know how
        break;
    case R.id.menuitem2:
        Log.i("This is Menu", "0");
        super.onBackPressed();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My Android Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" 

                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AndroidTabLayoutActivity"
             android:logo="@drawable/logo"
             android:label=""
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.droidnova.android.splashscreen.AndroidTabLayoutActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `startActivity(<Intent for your dashboard activity>)` instead of `super.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Then just change the fragment to the dashboard fragment. If you just call `super.onBackPressed()`, then your previous activity will be brought to the front. There is no guarantee, that it is your dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

in OnClick of home button start dashboard activity as

```
 home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(currentclass.this,dashboardactivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
              finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: My Home button is a button in actionbar, so preferably, I will going to insert it menuitem1 case. My dashboard is a fragment that is called in AndroidTablayoutActivity.class

Answer (score 0):

You say that the dashboard is a fragment in your AndroidTabLayoutActivity. Im supposing that you dont want to call that fragment from the current Activity you are in.

You could pass a parameter in the intent for opening AndroidTabLayoutActivity like this. (this code goes in the onOptionsItemSelected() method)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("type","dashboard");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the AndroidTabLayoutActivity in the onCreate method you could check if this parameter exists.

```
 if  ( getIntent().getStringExtra("type","splash").equals("dashboard")) {
//start dashboard
} else {
  //start splashscreen
}
```